# position: absolute and automatic width trough content

Tags: html, css

I created a little Tooltip thats in a Container. So there a two divs both with `position: absolute;`. They have to be position absolute or otherwise they will mess up the whole design.

```
.container_1 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;
     left: 20px;
}

.container_2 {
     position: absolute;
}

<div class="container_1"><div class="container_2">Full Name-Name</div></div>
```

I also have a CSS Triangle in the first container so that's why there are two containers.

In the Tooltip there is shown the Full Name of a user. But now I have the problem that the div isn't as wide as the content. So I fixed it through replacing space with `&nbsp;` but now there is the same problem with dash's. But the problem doesn't get fixed by replacing the dash with `&ndash;`. Anybody knows a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS:

```
.container_1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.container_2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yG5eF/

**Edit**: Sorry, totally misread it the first time.

Comment: That would do the opposite of what i want? But it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great solution! But overflow: hidden; and width: 95px; isn't necessary. Works also without it and also hides my CSS Triangle. But thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `white-space: no-wrap` does the trick. Thanks. No need of width.

Comment: @abhisekp It's `nowrap`.